How to test a worker thread in NodeJS?
I have a node script that uses a worker thread. I want to test it with Jest. The file is called, but the code is never executed.
Here is the function that calls the worker:
// index.ts 
function foo(){
  const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, "./worker.ts"));
  worker.on("message", (e) => {
   // do stuff
  });
}

Here is the worker:
// worker.ts
const { parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
const { doStuff } = require("./index");

parentPort?.on("message", async (e) => {
    const data = await doStuff(e);
    parentPort?.postMessage({ data });
 }
);


What am I doing wrong? I've tried to mock a Worker in Jest, but it's not called. I've also tried to compile worker.ts to a worker.js file before using it.

I don't see your [mcve] test, could you add that to your post please, and explain how you're invoking Jest (since there are a number of possible runtime arguments for both Jest, and Node itself when using Jest)?

The fix was to compile worker.ts to a .cjs file, because the worker was importing code from other typescript files.

The issue is that you have a stalemate in your code lol. Your main thread (index.ts) is waiting for messages from your child thread while your child thread (worker.ts) is also waiting for a message from your main thread before it executes the logic in it. You need to trigger this execution from your main thread.
To do this, add this to your index.ts code
worker.postMessage("some data");

This will broadcast a new message that will be received by your child thread and will thus execute doStuff and send a message back to your main thread

Yeah, I made a basic example instead of reproducing the whole code and forgot the postMessage line. So you're right, and you get an upvote, but it's not the final answer.
